# Accessing tweets from Twitter API

Tags: java, twitter

I need help making this code more efficient but still functions the same, such as by making it access the Twitter API fewer times. When I run this code for like 1 min, I get an error from Twitter saying that it exceeds limits.

```
List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();

       for (Status tweet : tweets) {

            if(!(tweet.getUser().getScreenName().toString().equals("gh") || tweet.getUser().getScreenName().toString().equals("gh"))){

                boolean found = false;

                List<Status> Stats=  tw.getHomeTimeline();
                for (Status StatList : Stats) {  

                    if(StatList.getTweetText().equals(tweet.getTweetText())){   
                        found = true;
                        break;
                        try {
                            System.out.println(tweet.getUser().getScreenName() );

                            Thread.sleep(2000);
                        } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        }
                    }else{
                        // nothing here                    
                    }
                }
                if (found) // you can move this and the initialisation(boolean found = false) out side the upper if statement
                    System.out.println("false");
                else
                    System.out.println("turn");

            }else{
                System.out.println("blocked");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What Twitter client library are you using? Could you please include enough context for us to tell what `result` is?

Answer (score 2):

Just a few hints that might better the code:

1. If you tend to access a structure for a given element multiple times with an operation on it, extract it in a local variable:

   ```
   tweet.getUser().getScreenName() // If its String, toString not required.
   ```
2. Have try..catch for statements that can cause the exception i.e put this out

   ```
   System.out.println(tweet.getUser().getScreenName() );
   ```
3. As your comment states, put the `boolean` out with the two states and have minimal print statements. If its for debugging, add comments or debug flag.
4. Having try..catch after break? Please check.
5. Check if `tweets` is `null` after

   ```
   List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
   ```
6. Check if `tweet` is `null` inside the `for` loop.
7. Apply (5) and (6) for Stats as well.

Answer (score 2):

- dead code should be removed
- store multiple accessed properties to variables like **@thepace**  mentioned
- use `braces` for single if statements also. This is a matter of taste, but your code will be less errorprone
- comments which doesn't explain **why** something is done should be removed. **What** is done should be explained by the code itself.
- this double checking if the screenname is "gh" isn't needed. You can't be more sure than sure.
- Calling `toString()` on a String is not necessary
- empty `else` blocks can be removed
- variable names should be using `camelCase` casing

**Refactoring**

after applying the above

```
List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();

for (Status tweet : tweets) {

    String userName = tweet.getUser().getScreenName();
    if(!(userName.equals("gh")){

        boolean found = false;

        List<Status> stats=  tw.getHomeTimeline();
        for (Status status : stats) {  
            String tweetText = tweet.getTweetText();
            if(status.getTweetText().equals(tweetText)){   
                found = true;
                break;
             }
         }
         if (found) {
             System.out.println("false");
         } else {
             System.out.println("turn");
         }
     } else {
         System.out.println("blocked");
     }
 }
```